# Where can I find country borders that matches MapBox tiles?

Tags: mapbox

I am using Mapbox and Leaflet to visualize a world map.
The map tile is based on the MapBox tiles that you can find and style upon creating MapBox project.
I tried to load the geometries of world countries from Natural Earth with the most accurate scale  1:10m million but I found out that a geojson border of Morocco for example is not matching the the border of Morocco in the MapBox baseline.

So where exactly I can find the geojson border of world countries that matches MapBox tile?

Answer (score 2):

Natural Earth is used at lower zoom levels, at some point it switches to more detailed OSM data from http://openstreetmapdata.com/data.

Hope that helps.